# Is there a machine readable format of the data tables in Particle Data Group PDFs?

Tags: particle-physics, specific-reference, data

Is there a machine-readable format of the tables of data in PDG documents such as this one?

http://pdg.lbl.gov/2011/download/rpp-2010-booklet.pdf

Something such as JSON, XML, CSV, HTML, or anything like that.

Comment: Did you see http://pdg.lbl.gov/2014/html/computer_read.html? The data format is old style proprietary but perfectly machine readable with a trivial reader program.

Comment: It's worth noting these that the format used for computer readable data in bulk is the Evaluated Nuclear Data File (ENDF) (a white-space delimenated columnar textfile). Available from several sources as there are multiple evaluating bodies (e.g. the Japanese have one that puts out the JENDFs). The stuff that appears in the PDG summaries are the bits that an experimenter needs in order to know which what to worry about in designing a experiment or equivalently which ENDFs to bother with in simulation.